# PHP - How to send post request using php curl instead of form submission and then redirect the page?

Tags: php, payment-gateway, form-submit, php-curl

I want to send a post request to `https://pep.shaparak.ir/gateway.aspx` which is a bank gateway. What sample codes exist is:

```
<center>Please Wait...</center>
<div style="display:none">
<form name='myform' method='post' action='https://pep.shaparak.ir/gateway.aspx'>
    <input type='text' name='terminal' value='<?=$terminalCode?>' />
    <input type='text' name='merchant' value='<?=$merchantCode?>' />
    .
    .
    .
</form>
</div>
<script>document.myform.submit()</script>
```

the user redirected to the page the bank wants..however it has security problems I guess, isn't it? Because the user can return back to the previous page and see what is inside inputs which are credentials for bank requests.
So I have been trying to use curl and send data with it:

```
$postFields = [
    'terminalCode' => $terminalCode,
    'merchantCode' => $merchantCode,
    .
    .
    .
];
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://pep.shaparak.ir/gateway.aspx");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($postFields));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($postFields));
$result = curl_exec($ch);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
curl_close($ch);
if(isset($info['url'])) {
    // Because I'm using Laravel.
    return redirect()->to($info['url']);
}
```

But now the problem is that it doesn't redirect to the page bank wants automatically.

How can I redirect the user to the page bank returns?

Comment: What does the API return upon a successful request?

Comment: Can you add a link to it's documentation?

Comment: The value of `$info['url']` is `https://pep.shaparak.ir/payment.aspx?n=KkLLrzcvjsGxZHdBOKpK2AE8NGPVF8+SqexHYdRG8CE=&Language=Fa` that `n` parameter can be anything else. It redirects to the bank but the response from the bank is: Time limitation for purchasing has been ended. BTW I'm doing it locally, might that be the problem?

Comment: The documentation is in Persian. Can you read Persian?

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry about security. PEP payments verify your identity by your electronic signature (the `sign` parameter that you send via the form). So even if someone has your merchant code, terminal id or anything else it doesn't really matter since PEP doesn't authorize any action without the electronic signature.

Comment: But what if I don't want to expose those two too?

Comment: Well, it's not possible. I know this design is not the best but this is what they did and it works.

Comment: Also, these are not so secret since the customer can see them on the gateway page itself.